# html5 local storage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, storage, local

How can I save html source code into HTML 5 local storage using an array or object.

for example i want to store the following input tags into local storage as an array(here its 3 input tags in   3 array elements) or in object

```
            <input type="text" class="in1" value="img1">
            <input type="text" class="in2" value="img2">
            <input type="text" class="in3" value="img3">
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: WHy would you need to save HTML in localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

Local storage only stores strings in key/value pairs so you won't be able store actual objects or arrays. What you can do is store inputs in a JSON object

```
  var inputs = {
        0:  '<input type="text" class="in1" value="img1">',
        1:  '<input type="text" class="in2" value="img2">',
        2:  '<input type="text" class="in3" value="img3">'
  }
```

Then you call:

```
   JSON.stringify(inputs)
```

stringify will return a string in a json format and you can store this string to localStorage

To store:

```
   localStorage.setItem('inputs', JSON.stringify(inputs))
```

To retrieve the result as an object you will need to use JSON.parse

```
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('inputs'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or there is another solution called, sessionvars, don't know the exact site, but if you do a search it can prove very useful for multiwebsite session storage too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would, but to answer your question:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" class="in1" value="img1">
    <input type="text" class="in2" value="img2">
    <input type="text" class="in3" value="img3"> 
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
localStorage.container = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
```

**JSFiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/jjHTL/

Comment: Note, I do not recommend doing this.